# How to automatically set active state

Tags: azure-devops

We are migrating our issue tracker from Youtrack to VSTS. I want to create a flow where a state of work is automatically switched to active when branch is created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't out of the box functionality. The solution I can come up with involves writing some code to do this yourself.

You can use Service Hooks to subscribe to events happening within VSTS. One Service Hook is [Git Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/events?toc=/vsts/integrate/toc.json&bc=/vsts/integrate/breadcrumb/toc.json#git.push). This happens whenever someone pushes code, so also when a new branch is pushed to the server. (You can't do this when a branch is created locally on the developers PC since there is no one there to tell you)

You could then let the Service Hook put a message on (for example) an [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/consumers?toc=/vsts/integrate/toc.json&bc=/vsts/integrate/breadcrumb/toc.json#azureservicebus). An [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) can then subscribe to the Service Bus and use the [VSTS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/vsts/) to update the work item.